# Circle smaller than 10 px

Tags: html, css

I have a PNG of a grey circle (1024 x 1024 resolution). 
I add it using `<img src="circle.png"/>`

However when i use CSS to set height anything below 10px it becomes really blocked. Like 10px is a perfect circle, 9px is a circle that looks like it has been in a car accident.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how can i make it smaller while it still remains a good rounded circle?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Screenshots? in general - why are you using a 1024x1024 image for a 10px wide element? You should use a smaller image.

Comment: Adding css ***height*** property can't make ***img*** tag block. Plase add jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because anything under 10px will make that circle under 1% and very small fractions of pixels, so the browser will provide an approximation to that, but it doesn't know if you have a circle or what, thus that approximation may be a bit weird.

Think of a pixel as an atom you can't divide. Still, you're asking to divide it, so the browser "thinks"

> "hey, I can't do that, but I'll try my best"

, thus it places pixels as close as possible, but your 0.023px and your 0.075px sizes will obviously be scattered quite randomly

Try using SVG for better rendering or images that are close to the size you need, or simply use CSS, a simple `border-radius:50%` will work

Answer (score 1):

how about making the circle with *CSS* :

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/fcgvh)**

*HTML :*

```
<div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    background:grey;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:9px;
    height:9px;
}
```